# Menses discharge salah

Tags: menses

Asalamu alaykum , my period was due 8 days ago but instead of my period I am getting light brownish-pinkish discharge , it’s not a lot but it’s still there . Sometimes a tiny bit of blood aswell , this hasn’t ever happened to me before, usually I get this discharge for one day and my period the next but this time is different . I know it’s there because when I go come home from work I wipe and see the brownish pink discharge , now when I check it’s light brown- light pink , I haven’t been praying. My question is should I pray??

Comment: Try to ask a doctor for help and maybe identify if there is an actual health problem. The rulings of menstruation has been described here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/70438

Comment: [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48386/periods-of-two-weeks-duration) might be helpful.