# Doubt of being impure

Tags: women, taharah, menses

I had period cramps and a yellow brownish vaginal discharge. I read somewhere that this is part of the menstruation since it was time for my menstrual 
cycle and therefore I didn't pray salah.
**Should I have prayed salah?** I was confused whether I'm on my period or not.

I took a gusul and later didn't get any further discharge.
**Also should I have to make up for the missed prayers ?**

Comment: [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48386/periods-of-two-weeks-duration) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yup should be coming in some hours, I don’t think you should. The brown colouration is due to the menstrual blood which is impure

Comment: But I still didn't get it. It's been more than 24 hours.