# In Ramadan should I not fast for 7 days because of menses?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, menses

Since it's Ramadan, I get my period soon. But the thing is, I usually bleed for 5 days only, NOT 7 days. Should I not fast for 7 days just to be safe? Do I fast again once the bleeding has stopped even if it's less than 7 days?

Comment: There's menses (hayd) and there's bleeding (istihadah), but most scholars agree that a menses might take up to >10 days. See also [periods of two weeks duration](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48386/periods-of-two-weeks-duration/48389#48389)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever the time of the *Menstruation Period* , you are supposed to NOT fast on your period,

All schools of Islamic jurisprudence agree that a woman in menstruation should not fast or pray. This is established in  based on the following hadith:

Mu’adhah said:

> I asked `Aishah, ‘Why must we make up the fasts missed due to our
>   menstruation, and not prayers?’ Aisha said, ‘That was what the
>   messenger of Allah told us to do. We were ordered to make up the
>   fasts, and we were ordered not to make up the prayers.’ (Narrated by
>   the Group)

sources : **http://www.myreligionislam.com/detail.asp?Aid=5899**
**http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-about-islam/cant-fast-menstruation/**