# Does this count as istihadah or menses?

Tags: women, menses

I had my period for longer than usual last month, almost 15 days, and then spotting with some light bleeding randomly (till today). I fasted as normal after it reached over 10 days since a scholar told me it’s istihada and the spotting also doesn’t count. But now I’m bleeding again and it’s supposed to be around the time for my second period this month. I’m confused, am I allowed to fast or not?

Comment: I think checking [Periods of two weeks duration](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48386/periods-of-two-weeks-duration) would be helpful.

Comment: @Medi1Saif so can i fast?

Comment: How can I answer this. The information I have is shared in the link above in which you could check.

Comment: @Medi1Saif yes but my situation was a bit different. Anyways i decided not to fast since it’s around the time for my second period, i hope that was the right thing to do